# Property in directive has different value then the controller one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Controller:

```
 constructor($scope) {
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.counter = 0;
            this.playerCells = [];
            this.$scope.$watch(() => this.playerCells, this.updateCounter(), true)

        }

updateCounter() {
    return () => {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.playerCells.forEach((item) => {
            if ( item.isShip === true ) {
                this.counter++;
                console.log("Ctrl counter "+this.counter)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Directive

```
export function fieldDir() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: require(...),
        scope: {
            cells: '=',
            counter: '=',
        },
        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.selectShip = function(item) {
                if ( item.isShip === false) {
                    item.isShip = true;
                } else {
                    item.isShip = false;
                }
                console.log("Dir counter " + $scope.counter)

            }
        }
    }
}

<field-dir cells="vm.playerCells" counter="vm.counter"></field-dir>
```

I'm looking for the value of counter in both the controller and the directive. The console.log returns the following values after the $watch is being triggered for the first time:

```
Directive log: Dir counter 0
Controller log: Ctrl counter 1
```

I'm guessing the directive is being instantiated first by the console.log order and is taking the initial value of `this.counter` before `$watch` triggers the listener function.

Is there any way I can fix this or is there a better alternative to what I'm doing now ?

Comment: When you set up the watch, you're calling the function instead of passing it. Replace `this.updateCounter()` with `this.updateCounter`

Comment: @ChrisG Now it doesnt update the counter at all.

Comment: I just saw that `updateCounter()` returns a function, so something else is amiss.